# Bootstrap Datepicker attributes not being set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to set the startDate for my datepicker along with autoclose:true. However, it doesn't work.

Can you please point to what I am doing wrong? I have the code up on jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/alagappanr/9Xek7/

```
Effective Date:  <input type=text size=10 id=effectivedate maxlength=10 name=efdate><br/>
Expiration Date: <input type=text size=10 maxlength=10 name=exdate id=expirationdate>
```

The JavaScript that I have written for the datepicker is as follows:

```
jQuery(function() {
     var efDP = jQuery("#effectivedate");
     var exDP = jQuery("#expirationdate");
     efDP.datepicker("setDate", new Date());
     efDP.datepicker("update");
     exDP.datepicker("setDate", new Date(Date.now()+259200000));
     exDP.datepicker("update");
     exDP.datepicker({autoclose:true});
     efDP.datepicker({
         startDate: new Date(),
         autoclose:true,
         });
     efDP.on("changeDate", function(ev){
             var effectDate = new Date(jQuery("#effectivedate").val());
             jQuery("#expirationdate").datepicker("setDate", new Date(effectDate.getTime()+259200000));
             jQuery("#expirationdate").datepicker("update");
         });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update a non-existing datepicker on the first few lines. `exDP.datepicker({autoclose:true});` creates a new instance. You have to set the options directly:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var efDP = jQuery("#effectivedate").datepicker({autoclose:true});
    var exDP = jQuery("#expirationdate").datepicker({autoclose:true});

    efDP.datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('update');
    exDP.datepicker("setDate", new Date(Date.now()+259200000)).datepicker('update');
    efDP.on("changeDate", function(e){
        exDP.datepicker("setDate", new Date(e.date.getTime() +259200000)).datepicker('update');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/svierkant/9Xek7/7/

Please take a look at the documentation, to see if you can reuse objects from events. On the first line of your `.on` function, your are getting a string from an object (`.val()`) and making a `Date` object from it again. The [`changeDate` event](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/events.html#changedate) however, returns a Date object (which can be reused). Easier coding, more readable and maintainable code.

Comment: The reason I had to call setDate and update separately was to highlight the set date by default. By changing it to update instead of setDate, the value is being set, but the highlight does not happen.

Comment: @AlagappanRamu That sounds like a good reason to use ``update``, but there is no need to use ``setDate`` as well. I've updated your jsfiddle.

Comment: It does not highlight the date without setDate. Screenshot without highlight: http://postimg.org/image/fgqpg3ard/. Screenshot with highlight: http://postimg.org/image/n3jt4d613/. 
I am not sure if there is a way to get the highlight just by using update...

Comment: @AlagappanRamu You are right, I missed that! I updated my answer and jsfiddle. I don't think there is way to do it at once. This issue on GitHub is worth reading: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/575

Answer (score 1):

You should use below coding style.

```
var efDP = jQuery("#effectivedate");
 efDP.datepicker({
         startDate: new Date(),
         autoclose:true,
         });
 efDP.datepicker("update", new Date(Date.now()+259200000));
```